# ¿Porqué no muestra correctamente los <td> de una tabla?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, css

tengo una tabla creada y que quedaría de la siguiente forma si todo fuese bien (la imagen está tomada sin ocultar campos ni nada):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora uso este código para ocultar las columnas H1 y H2. Están dispuestas de tal manera que tienen el mismo nombre pero cambiando un número al final (este código lo ejecuto en el `$(document).ready`):

```
try{
        var n = 1;
        while(true){
            var nomEti = "hOcultas"+n;
            //alert(nomEti);
            var oculto = document.getElementById(nomEti);
            oculto.style.display = "none";
            n++;
        }
    }catch(err){
        //alert(err.message);
    }
```

Y quedaría tal que así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta aquí todo bien, ahora cuando uso el siguiente código para mostrarlas cuando pulsa el botón "Mostrar":

```
try{
        var n = 1;
        while(true){
            var nomEti = "hOcultas"+n;
            //alert(nomEti);
            var oculto = document.getElementById(nomEti);
            oculto.style.display = "block";
            n++;
        }
    }catch(err){
        //alert(err.message);
    }
```

El resultado me sale así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿A qué se puede deber?

Saludos.

Comment: podrias poner tu codigo html de la tabla, es decir el codigo de como generas la tabla sin ocultar los campos

Comment: ¿Estás segur@ que tus celdas H tenían `display` en `block` antes de ocultarlas? Te sugiero que antes de ocultarlas, hagas un `alert()` para saber qué valor de `display` tienen asignado al cargarlas por primera vez, para que sea a ese valor al que regresen cuando las quieras mostrar. Lo otro: al "Mostrar", agregas una condición que genera `rowspan`, que al ocultar no habías hecho ¿por qué lo haces al mostrar?

Comment: Como dice quinqui, es probable que display block te este generando el problema, seguramente si lo cambias por `oculto.style.display = "inherit";`deberia mostrarse como corresponde

Comment: @DiegoAvila El código lo genero con php, y no se porque al poner el fragmento de php donde se genera las etiquetas me quita los elementos html (me refiero al editar el post y añadir el código).

Comment: un `td` por defecto tiene el valor `table-cell` en la propiedad `display`, al poner display block no se está mostrando como debería

Comment: @quinqui A ver, la primera captura que hay es una captura que he realizado sin ocultar nada. La segunda captura es cuando los oculto con el código que he dejado. Lo del `rowspan` olvídalo, es un error de unas pruebas que he estado haciendo, pero no afecta al resultado. Voy a editarlo en el post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

una solucion practica seria usar Jquery, a su vez agregar una place o ids, en este ejemplo uso clase:
**HTML**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="Mostrar/Ocultar Row1" onclick="mostrarOcultar();">
<table id="myTable" border="1"
<tr id="row1">
  <td class="td_hide">Celda 1</td>
  <td>Celda 2</td>
  <td>Celda 3</td>
</tr>
<tr id="row2">
  <td class="td_hide">Celda 4</td>
  <td>Celda 5</td>
  <td>Celda 6</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**JAVASCRIPT/JQUERY**

```
function mostrarOcultar(){
$('.td_hide').toggle();

}
```

**EL EVENTO TOGGLE** muestra / oculta un elemento en este caso un td(columna) detecta automaticamente si esta oculto lo muestra y sino lo hace a la inversa
te dejo el link de prueba:
[LINK DE PRUEBA](https://jsfiddle.net/quehwpLh/3/)

Comment: Perfecto, me ha funcionado. Muchas gracias.